# Issue with Installing Anaconda packages

Tags: package-management, anaconda

I'm trying to install into anaconda a pywinauto package which I downloaded from [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pywinauto/files). However I keep getting this error

```
C:\>C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -m conda install C:\Users\beh\pywinaut-0.6.6-py36_0.tar.bz2

Downloading and Extracting Packages
* None: ####################################################################################################### | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: - WARNING conda.gateways.disk:exp_backoff_fn(49): Uncaught backoff with errno EEXIST 17
failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while installing package 'None'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
FileExistsError(17, 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists')
```

My org's firewall restrictions block access to conda or pip and thus I have to download the packages separately and install with `conda install`

Appreciate help in resolving this.

---

Edit: Realise that this happens with All packages. Appreciate any help.

Comment: The file (apparently)  already exists. Does `conda list` not show `pywinauto` is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated your environment using `conda activate envname`, replacing envname with your environment name?

Then try calling the conda install with `conda install C:\Users\beh\pywinaut-0.6.6-py36_0.tar.bz2`. You shouldn't need the extra python path on that line